# ListView memory leak PR sitting for almost a year

Tags: xamarin.forms

Does anyone know what's going on with this PR? It's been sitting in limbo for almost a year.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/938

Has the rebase been completed?

Comment: If you badly need this I would recommend rebasing the PR yourself and re-submitting it (with a link to the older one), since you can't know what the original author's engagement to get it completed.